# Successive clock() operations over identical intervals have incremental consumption. Why?

Tags: c++, time

While utilizing the clock() function in time.h I noticed some behavior I could not explain. In the code below I am using identical for loops to eat up processing time.  I don't see any logical reason why one would consistently take longer than the other, but based on what I am seeing with the clock() function it would seem that each iteration takes roughly 7 - 10% longer. What is the reasoning behind this?

I added a typical representation of the output.  The compiled ASM is over 1300 lines of code.  I didn't think it would be constructive to post, but if you need to see it I can e-mail it to you.

output:

```
a: 3835
b: 4155
Percentage increase in execution time: 8%
c: 4423
Percentage increase in execution time: 15%
d: 4699
Percentage increase in execution time: 22%
e: 4976
Percentage increase in execution time: 29%
```

source:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  clock_t a, b, c, d, e;
  unsigned int aResult, bResult, cResult, dResult, eResult;

  a = clock();
  for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++);
  aResult = a;
  std::cout << "a: " << aResult << std::endl;

  b = clock();
  bResult = b;
  for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++);
  std::cout << "b: " << bResult << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Percentage increase in execution time: " 
    << 100 * (bResult - aResult)/aResult << "%" <<std::endl;

  c = clock();
  for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++);
  cResult = c;
  std::cout << "c: " << cResult << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Percentage increase in execution time: " 
    << 100 * (cResult - aResult)/aResult << "%" <<std::endl;

  d = clock();
  for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++);
  dResult = d;
  std::cout << "d: " << dResult << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Percentage increase in execution time: " 
    << 100 * (dResult - aResult)/aResult << "%" <<std::endl;

  e = clock();
  for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++);
  eResult = e;
  std::cout << "e: " << eResult << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Percentage increase in execution time: " 
    << 100 * (eResult - aResult)/aResult << "%" <<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: What is the output of this program? What is the assembly of this program? What compiler are you using? How are you compiling/what compiler switches are you using? This program is C++, why is this tagged with C not C++?

Comment: If I would have tagged it c++ people would have complained that it had elements of c. Regardless.  it has been changed.

Comment: The  `clock` returns the current time. No wonder the time increases by constant amount after each test is run, ie. about ~3% of `aResult` on each loop. Doing `(eResult-aResult)/aResult` is not ok. You need to compare start and stop times before and after operation, ie: `start = clock(); for (...); stop = clock(); *Result = stop - start;`, Then calculate the difference. That way you get how many clocks the loop run.

Comment: The documentation I was reading indicated that clock() returns the processor time consumed by the program.  Not the time. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/clock/

Comment: I can't believe this code doesn't puke on reasonably beefed hardware. It is feasible (and in fact it happens on my game rig) that `a` will be *zero*, ultimately triggering division by zero in all calculations from `b` onward. Regardless, your calculations are simply wrong. You're measure time since `a` on *all* loops, so naturally the farther you go the more time has gone by. Look at the difference between each, not relative to `a`. 8%, 7%, 7%, 7%. So what's the problem ?

Comment: I meant the processor time. How do you measure how much processor time a operation took? You remember the current processor time (`start = clock()`)  then run the operation you want to measure `for(...);` then get the processor time `stop = clock()`. The operation took `stop - start` processor time.

Comment: Doing division on `unsigned int` will result in integer number. ie. `3/2 = 1`. You need to cast to `float` or `double`, `((float)dResult - (float)aResult) / (float)aResult`.

Comment: WhozCraig, Obviously my machine is far slower than yours.  I was under the impression that each function call eg " a = clock()" sets off an individual timer.  that is why the math is done the way it is.  Are you saying that the clock() function is based on a different event?

Comment: `gcc8.2 -O2` optimizes `for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++);` away, so it should take 0 clocks.

Comment: That's not how it works.. [Read the documentation.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/clock).  *"Returns the approximate processor time used by the process since the beginning of an implementation-defined era related to the program's execution. "* - in short, is is accumulated. successive calls will report larger and larger numbers, all relative to when the process started (more or less). There are plenty of caveats, so personally I stick with `std::chrono`, which frankly is a much nicer interface regardless.

Comment: Kamil,  I compiled with O2 and there is only a could of tic's difference.  You are correct.

Comment: WhozCraig.  That would make sense.  I misunderstood and thought the execution time was based of the initialization of the value.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having is that the statistics you are printing are incorrect. `(bResult - aResult)/aResult` and so are on are *not* telling you the percentage of increase in the time intervals, as aResult is the time since the start of the program - not just the time of the for loop. Furthermore `(dResult - aResult)/aResult` and the others are always comparing your latest result to the first result when you need to compare it to the previous result.

If you change your expressions to be the form `((eResult - dResult) - (bResult - aResult))/(bResult - aResult)` you should get a more consistent answer. That is, at each iteration you need to compare the most recent interval `(eResult - dResult)` with the first interval `(bResult - aResult)` and not the first time.

Comment: Now that I understand that all instances of clock() are based off of the program execution, this makes sense. Judging by the fact that the increases were roughly the same, if I were to change the code to as what you described I would probably be +/- 1 or 2 %.

Comment: Also, the for loop is most likely optimized away by the compiler. The code (when optimized) measures the cost of clock() and of printing, not the loop. This does not change the main observation in the answer. As  Kamil Cuk comments on the question.